# Problemas alinhamento menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

Tenho um menu `dropdown` no WordPress na aba de **Serviços**, só que quando redimensiono a página com zoom, o menu não está seguindo o seu elemento pai,

Segue imagem e código.

[image: exemplo 1]
[image: exemplo 2]

```css
ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    
}

ul.sub-menu #menu-item-556, #menu-item-555, #menu-item-554, #menu-item-553, #menu-item-552 {
    padding: 0px;
}



li#menu-item-721:hover ul.sub-menu{
    display: block;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 90px;
    right:7%;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #23b9d7;
    padding-top:40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li#menu-item-721:hover ul.sub-menu:after{
    content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid #23b9d7;
 top: -10px;
 left: 64.5%;
}

li#menu-item-721:hover ul.sub-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#menu-item-556 {
    background-image: url('../hospitaldoiphone/img/iphone.png');
    z-index: 999;
    width: 67px;
    height: 137px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 80px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}


#menu-item-555 {
    background-image: url('../hospitaldoiphone/img/ipad.png');
    z-index: 999;
    width: 120px;
    height: 136px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 80px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

#menu-item-554 {
    background-image: url('../hospitaldoiphone/img/macbook.png');
    z-index: 999;
    width: 242px;
    height: 140px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 80px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

#menu-item-553 {
    background-image: url('../hospitaldoiphone/img/imac.png');
    z-index: 999;
    width: 140px;
    height: 143px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 80px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

#menu-item-552 {
    background-image: url('../hospitaldoiphone/img/applewatch.png');
    z-index: 999;
    width: 120px;
    height: 139px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 80px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}


#menu-item-556 a:hover, #menu-item-555 a:hover, #menu-item-554 a:hover, #menu-item-553 a:hover, #menu-item-552 a:hover, #menu-item-556:hover, #menu-item-555:hover, #menu-item-554:hover, #menu-item-553:hover, #menu-item-552:hover  {
    transform: scale(1.05)
    
}

#menu-item-556 a, #menu-item-555 a, #menu-item-554 a, #menu-item-553 a, #menu-item-552 a{
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
    
}

#menu-item-556 a {
    width: 67px;
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 150px;
    
}

#menu-item-555 a {
    width: 120px;
    height: 160px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

#menu-item-554 a {
    width: 242px;
    height: 160px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

#menu-item-553 a {
    width: 140px;
    height: 160px;
    padding-top: 150px;
   
}
#menu-item-552 a {
    width: 120px;
    height: 160px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                <ul><li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-25"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/">HOME</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/empresa/">EMPRESA</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-721"><a href="/hospital-iphone/iphone/">SERVIÇOS</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-556"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/iphone/">IPHONE</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-555"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/ipad/">IPAD</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-554" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-554"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/macbook/">MACBOOK</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-553" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-553"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/imac/">IMAC</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-552" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-552"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/apple-watch/">APPLE WATCH</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/desbloqueio/">DESBLOQUEIO</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/blog/">BLOG</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-last menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/contato/">CONTATO</a></li>
</ul>            </nav>
```

Comment: Cara com o que vc postou não da para simular o erro, vc não teria algum link que desse para acessar o site?

Comment: opa, tenho sim, aqui está https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/hospital-iphone/

Comment: Cara eu dei uma olhada lá e vou te dar minha opinião. Vc só vai conseguir resolver isso Se trocar todas as medidas que estão em PX por %, pois o ZOOM do Browser escala o tamanho dos elementos, e como não tem relação de PX com % eles desalinham mesmo... Eu não me preocuparia com o Zoom que o usuário faz no Browser e som com a Responsividade do Site como um todo! (inclusive eu consegui alinha na mão com %, mas ainda está buggando quando da Zoom com o Browser)

Comment: todas as medidas da página?

Comment: Sobre o tratamento de PX para % pode fazer só no seu "menu/navbar", pesquise sobre o assunto do Zoom do Browser antes. Agora sobre o Site ser responsivo isso eu indico **fortemente** até pq funcionar em todas as telas é requisito do Google e fator importante de rankeamento nas pesquisa!

Comment: eu pesquisei bastante, mas não achei nada que fosse relevante

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver gente, só foi necessário trocar o atributo right no css pelo margin-left, que o menu ficou fixo.